# Probability question: Estimating the number of attempts needed to exhaustively try all possible placements in a word search

Tags: search, probability

Would it be reasonable to systematically try all possible placements in a [word search](http://www.halloweengames101.com/halloween-word-search-hard.jpg)?

Grids commonly have dimensions of 15*15 (15 cells wide, 15 cells tall) and contain about 15 words to be placed, each of which can be placed in 8 possible directions. So in general it seems like you can calculate all possible placements by the following:
width*height*8_directions_to_place_word*number of words

So for such a grid it seems like we only need to try 15*15*8*15 = 27,000 which doesn't seem that bad at all. I am expecting some huge number so either the grid size and number of words is really small or there is something fishy with my math.

Comment: It's actually even less than that. E.g. when searching for an N letter word, horizontal, left-to-right, you only need to search for starting letters in the leftmost 15 - N + 1 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Formally speaking, assuming that `x` is number of rows and `y` is number of columns you should sum all the probabilities of every possible direction for every possible word.

Inputs are: `x`, `y`, `l` (average length of a word), `n` (total words)

so you have

- horizontally a word can start from `0` to `x-l` and going right or from l to `x` going left for each row: `2x(x-l)`
- same approach is used for vertical words: they can go from `0` to `y-l` going down or from `l` to `y` going up. So it's `2y(y-l)`
- for diagonal words you shoul consider all possible start positions `x*y` and subtract `l^2` since a rect of the field can't be used. As before you multiply by 4 since you have got 4 possible directions: `4*(x*y - l^2)`.

Then you multiply the whole result for the number of words included:

```
total = n*(2*x*(x-l)+2*y*(y-l)+4*(x*y-l^2)
```